# Why do jQuery's show() and hide() methods trigger a fade?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to show and hide tweets on a client's side right now, but jQuery is collapsing the element on `hide()` and fading it in on `show()`.

Relevent HTML:

```
<aside>
  <div class="tweet-author">
    <p class="name">Graham Swan</p>
    <p class="position">Managing Partner</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tweet">
    <blockquote>Just had the greatest cup of coffee ever!</blockquote>
    <div class="clearfix">
      <time>2 minutes ago <span>via</span> Twitter</time>
      <a href="#">Hide Tweets</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Relevant JavaScript:

```
// Hide tweets when "Hide Tweets" link is clicked
$(document).on('click', 'div.tweet > div.clearfix > a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("div.tweet").hide(function() {
    $("div.tweet-author > p.name").html("Show Recent Tweets");
    $("div.tweet-author > p.position").html("By the iNovia Team");
    $("aside").addClass("click-to-show-tweets");
  });
});

// Show tweets when "Show Recent Tweets" link is clicked
$(document).on('click', 'aside.click-to-show-tweets', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("div.tweet").show(function() {
    $("div.tweet-author > p.name").html("Graham Swan");
    $("div.tweet-author > p.position").html("Managing Partner");
    $("aside").removeClass("click-to-show-tweets");
  });
});
```

jQuery is performing the following actions:

- Collapsing the `div.tweet` element instead of immediately hiding it when `hide()` is called.
- Fading in (in webkit browsers) or expanding (in moz browsers) the `div.tweet` element instead of immediately showing it when `show()` is called.

I've tried both v1.7.2 and v.1.8.2 of jQuery, as well as different browsers, but all yield the same effect.

**Does anyone know why this is happening?**

You can see a live example at http://grahamswan.com/clients/inovia if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method signature you are using (`.hide( duration [, callback] )`) is for animated hiding. The signature for immediate hiding is simply `$("div.tweet").hide();` To hide the element instantly, you can pass an argument of `0` for the duration right before your callback argument.

Better yet, simply invoke the function right after you call `$("div.tweet").hide();`. You don't really need a callback; the hide action is synchronous.

```
$("div.tweet").hide();
(function() {
    $("div.tweet-author > p.name").html("Show Recent Tweets");
    $("div.tweet-author > p.position").html("By the iNovia Team");
    $("aside").addClass("click-to-show-tweets");
  })();
```

Comment: Well *that* was a silly mistake. Thanks for your help! I also realized that the reason the elements were fading back in was because I had a keyframe animation assigned to them on page load. All is working as expected now!

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the duration of you hide and show.

```
$("div.tweet").hide(0, function() ...

$("div.tweet").show(0, function() ...
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gpj6e/)